# How to Schedule a task to run at every day at 9 AM in Node?

Tags: node.js, cron, node-schedule

I have checked on [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

I have done the same to run at Every 9AM but it runs more than once per day.

```
let tenSecCron = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 9 * * *', async () => {
    this.runJobs();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by, it runs more than once a day? Can you please specify the interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use [object literal syntax](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#object-literal-syntax) as follows:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 9, minute: 0} , async () => {
    this.runJobs();
});
```

Beside this, it should be noted `node-schedule` is an in-memory scheduler and as such it is not based on `cron`. As a consequence scheduling will only work as long as the node.js process is running. If it is restarted you may experience strange effects like your jobs get scheduled right away.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct cron expression is this:

```
0   0   9   ?   *   *   *
```

If your scheduler defies the above expression, [later.js](https://bunkat.github.io/later/) is a good library for accurate results.

Comment: As a variation `'0   0   9   1-31   *   *   * '` should also work. However, the schedule `'0 0 9 * * *'` trialled by the OP should also work given that hour schedule is 24 hours as documented.